# Validating XSS Vulnerability in Rest API

Tags: xss, api

I am performing security testing on a Rest API and it is a POST method. I injected a XSS script in a body parameter and the API responded with '400 Bad Request' error, but the response displays the XSS script that I have injected in the request payload.

If the response is '200 OK' and if the response body displays the XSS script, then I would have concluded this as a vulnerability, because the XSS script would have been stored and reacted when the respective page is opened in a web browser (if the web application is also weak in security). However, in this case, the response is '400 Bad Request', so do I need to still consider this as a vulnerability?

Answer (score 2):

In your case, you perform a POST request and the response give you back your script, it's called a self-XSS.

That's not very useful and not a serious vulnerability in itself, beaucause the purpose of an XSS attack, is to be executed on other user, other accounts, not only yourself. 
It can be transformed in a traditionnal XSS vulnerability if your API provide some sort of error management system, that could display the message without any sanitisation.

Answer (score 2):

> so do I need to still consider this as a vulnerability?

It depends on the details that you have not shared with us. I often have a hard time with raising XSS tickets against APIs because, by definition, an API is returning data and it's the browser / client / javascript that is choosing to execute the API response as code, in which case I would raise a "data-vs-code confusion" ticket against the web client. But in some cases it is the API's fault.

## Example where it's the API's fault

If the API is returning HTML content like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
...
Content-Type: text/html
...
<HTML>
...
You submitted:
"<script>alert(0)</script>"
</HTML>
```

Then that's clearly the API's fault because the browser has no way to know that `<script>alert(0)</script>` was meant to be text and not code.

However,

## Example where it's not the API's fault

If the API is clearly returning data, for example:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
...
Content-Type: application/json
...
{"errmsg": "You submitted: \"<script>alert(0)</script>\""}
```

then that's fine because the API is clearly marking this as data, and the javascript client would need to do something very *very* wrong for that script to get executed.

---

## Summary

If I were you, I would keep digging until you can actually trigger a script alert popup, and then decide whether it's the API or the UI that's at fault.

Just to comment on @fmgp's answer: I agree that self-XSS is technically not a vulnerability, it's still sloppy coding practice and should still be pointed out and fixed. For example, that code may get copied into somewhere that is actually dangerous, or an attacker may find a way to trigger that code via a phishing link, commonly by exploiting frameworks that automatically promote GETs with URL params into a POST when there is no GET handler.